# Need to find all Messaging Apps in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to find all applications (among installed ones) that can open SMS. I have already found Gallery applications through the following method:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
newIntent.setType("image/*");
allApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(newIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

It gives me the list of all apps that can open images. Is there any similar way by which I can find all apps that can open SMS Messages?

Comment: NO..he doesn't want to app which can send SMS..not *the list of all apps installed* @Abdellah

Answer (score 1):

You need to set set type as `vnd.android-dir/mms-sms`

Try this code :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:123456789");  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);  
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS text");
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS text");
intent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```

Hop it will help you :)

Comment: @SweetWicher: Your First code gives me closest results but it shows Viber and Whatsapp also .... but these apps use Internet to send Messages ... not SMS Messages. Specifically I only need SMS Applications. Such as defauls Messaging App and Google Hangouts etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your Text");
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
startActivity(sendIntent);
```